# How to update a given row in Excel file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, row, cell, updates

How to update a given row in Excel file using Python?
Knowing that after loading my data I'm able to delete one row based on value, as my below code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

current_dir = Path(__file__).parent if '__file__' in locals() else 
Path.cwd()
EXCEL_FILE = current_dir / 'MyData.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)
........
........
........
if event == 'Remove':
sg.Submit()
KeyValue= values['DATA'] #'DATA' is the name of colum where I want to delete row
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)
df = df[df.DATA != KeyValue]
df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
```

So how to apply similar reasoning to update a given row based on value choosen from column "DATA"?

Comment: It is not possible to update one row in an excel file as it is a zip-xml file. You can overwrite the entire file.

Comment: mmm I see, how to achive that using "file overwiting" methode in my above example ?

Comment: @СергейКох, Could you please let me know how to achieve this procedure of updating values by overwriting files ?